# Input Data to next available row Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

Hello everyone is there anyway to get the next empty row in excel and then allow data to be input into that row? I have looked on the internet and found nothing that looks like this. One idea I came up with was to add a row evertime and just input into that row, but I was just wondering if there is any easier way to go about this. any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to be careful with on .usedrange is that it can select a row with ghost data on it (where data may have been deleted, but it has left some legacy data behind- such as formats).  Here, this will leave you with blank rows that need to be deleted.

If you have any column in your data that cannot be empty, then its pretty easy- just use the

```
range("a1").end(xldown).row
```

method.  If you are looking for the next available empty row (where any column can be populated/empty), you could use the find function to get it.  Something like;

```
Sub UnusedRow()

Dim lStartRow As Long
Dim lUnusedRow As Long

lStartRow = 3  'starting row no in case you have blank rows at the top
lUnusedRow = lStartRow - 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Do While lStartRow = lUnusedRow + 1
    lUnusedRow = lStartRow
    lStartRow = Cells.Find("*", Cells(lUnusedRow, 1), , , xlByRows, xlNext).Row + 1
Loop
On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The advantage of this is it selects the true next empty row (ie even where more data exists after the row it finds).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [UsedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215923%28office.11%29.aspx) property in Excel.